# Do I need a visa for Croatia?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, croatia

We have a 16 day trip of Austria, Hungary, Czech Republic, and Croatia. We got a Schengen visa with one month validity and will stay 10 days in the schengen area. We will spend 8 days in the Schengen area, and then enter Croatia on the 9th day.

My schengen visa is double entry and we will not enter the schengen again after visiting Croatia as we'll fly back to India from Dubrovnik.

So is our visa is sufficient to visit Croatia or do we need separate visa for it?

Answer (score 5):

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), the database used by airline staff states the following:

> **The following are exempt from holding a visa:**
>
> Passengers with a double
> or multiple entry "C" visa, valid for all Schengen Member States . The
> visa must be valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa
> exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.

So, as you have the Schengen Visa and is is valid for a full month this is more than enough to cover your entire trip, you don't need anything else.